# Poissonian nature of photon count

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I am trying to use poissonian distribution to validate photon emission of x-ray source. Photons counts are recorded at 100ms intervals using a photon counting detector. If the photon distribution is Poissonian then we can deduce that source is ok, otherwise we can predict that source has a problem.

I used Minitab to compare observed and expected number of counts, which gives a correct result. But my aim is to program the validation process. But when I tried to calculate Poisson probabilities manually, it seems all wrong. Counts are bin center values. The mean of the distribution is 2105,

`count        1972   1999  2026  2053  2081  2108  2135  2162  2189  2216`

`Freq         3       10    30     66   100   105    93    65    23    5`

These are the corresponding probabilities which is calculated using Excel Poisson function (POISSON.DIST)

`0.000131   0.000621    0.00205 0.004721    0.007624    0.008656    0.006879    0.003885    0.001567    0.000453`

Those probability values make no sense at all. Can someone explain what I have done wrong and how to calculate correct probabilities and expected frequencies?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you create bins? As I understand, you have data (counts) recorded every 100 ms, why not to use the data as is and apply some goodness of fit test to it, maybe chi-square test?

Comment: @kludg Thanks for the idea. We have already done that step, Service users are expected to use those results. However , we thought comparing two simple bar graph tends to give clear visual perception for ordinary users. ( Like minitab GOF test for Poisson )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel values are the probability of getting exactly your bin center value.  They sum to about $0.036$  and your bins are $27$ wide.  $27 \cdot 0.036 \approx 1$.  You should get the value for each number of counts from $2095$ through $2121$ and add them up to get the probability of your $2108$ bin.  It will not be far from $27 \cdot 0.008656$.  Now compare these probabilities to the fraction of events in each bin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, You are absolutely correct. I forgot to use bin width. Now it make sense.